# mod_rewrite is not working - at all

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This is driving me crazy.. Can't figure out whats wrong here..

Can't get mod_rewrite to work.. Nothing..

So here I try to redirect everyting to google.com

## apache.conf (update)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public/www

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^    http://www.google.com/ [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

## apache.conf

```
RewriteEngine on

#   Test
RewriteRule ^           http://www.google.com/ [L,R=301]

#   redirect non-active subdomains to 'www'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    \.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^(sub|www)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^               http://www.domain.com [L,R=301]

#   put 'www' as subdomain if none is given
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)               http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#   www.domain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public/www
</VirtualHost>

#   sub.domain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public/sub
</VirtualHost>
```

Not working

Here you can see loaded modules

```
root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb /var/www/dyntest.dk # apache2ctl -M
apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for dyntest-amd-3700-2gb
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Thu Jan 30 14:33:34 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 geoip_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your .htaccess: `ThisIsNotSupposedToWork!!!!`.  If that doesn't generate an internal server error, your `AllowOverride` is set to `None`.

Comment: have updated my question.. Im not using htaccess for this.. everything is in .conf

Comment: Move your rewrite config to a VirtualHost.

Comment: have moved the rewrite to a vhost, but still not working.. "apache.conf (update)" question updated

Comment: forgot `RewriteEngine on` :D